# Replace Text in Word documents using R and RDCOMClient

Tags: r, excel, ms-word, rdcomclient

Using RDCOMClient, we can directly replace values in Excel cells, e.g.

```
range <- sheet$Range('A1')
range[['Value']] <- 1.2
```

In Word, Texts can be retrieved from the `Text` property of a range object, e.g.

```
word.doc[['Tables']][[1]]$Cell(2, 2)[['Range']][['Text']]
# "12/28/2022\r\a"
```

But while the [Documentation of the range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.text) says that the `Text` property can be used to retrieve or set the text of the range, this does not work in RDCOMClient:

```
word.doc[['Tables']][[1]]$Cell(2, 2)[['Range']][['Text']] <- "test"
# Error in word.doc[["Tables"]][[1]]$Cell(2, 2)[["Range"]][["Text"]] <- "test" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is there a better way to edit the content of a cell or any other range/selection in Word?

If there is no way to do that, would selecting and Selection()$TypeText() or SearchReplace in the Range be more advisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work when you first get the Range object (from Word's viewpoint) and then set its Text property, e. g.:

```
library("RDCOMClient")

app  <-  COMCreate("Word.Application")
doc <- app$Documents()$Open('path_to_your_file.docx'))

## get the VBA object first:
the_range  <- doc[['Tables']][[1]]$Cell(2, 2)[['Range']]

## assign its Text property:
the_range[['Text']] = "No cell is an island\n
                       Entire of itself;\n
                       Every cell needs a piece of content,\n
                       A part of the main."

doc$Save()
```

Comment: Do you know why the assignment is necessary here?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I just got lucky after considering that Range is a class in VBA, Text being one of its properties or methods (according to the RDCOMClient's documentation, the difference is *"a little nebulous"*), so I thought it might help to retrieve the Range as an R object to set its property 'Text' later on.

Comment: btw, package {officer} might also be helpful: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officedown-for-word.html